# Как заставить приложение, открытое в нескольких вкладках браузера, работать как одно

Tags: javascript

Пожалуйста помогите разобраться.

Есть приложение, которое имеет 2 вкладки.
На первой вкладке мы смотрим какой выбран цвет, на второй выбираем сам цвет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне сделать так, чтобы это приложение работало корректно если я открою его в нескольких вкладках браузера.
Если я открою его в двух вкладках, это будет 2 приложения работающих независимо друг от друга, я бы хотел чтобы это работало как одно целое, сколько бы вкладок я ни открыл.

Как я могу это сделать, какие технологии для этого используются?

Мне нужен сервер?

Comment: Ответ зависит от того, должно ли оно работать таким же образом, если 2 вкладки открыты на разных ПК

Comment: @Andrei Khotko Ну вообще нет, только на одном ПК. А если на разных ПК, то уже нужен сервер насколько понимаю, да?

Answer (score 3):

`window.addEventListener('storage', function(e) { }`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API

отслеживание изменения `localStorage` в соседних вкладках